# Catching exceptions/errors

Tags: python, loops, csv, exception, program-entry-point

I'm a total beginner at Python and I want your detailed advice on something.

So i created this loop down below for a script which has a first input "gene_name", read from a .csv file. How do I write code to catch the case in which the "gene_name" is none, i.e. `gene_name = row.strip()` has nothing in  that row.

I am very confused about creating a custom exception(not sure if i'm using that word right), mainly about how to fill up the general pattern of the try-except thing.

Thanks!

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  with open('gene_list.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader: 
        gene_name = row.strip()
        probes_dict = get_probes_from_genes(gene_name) 
        expression_values, well_ids, well_coordinates, donor_names =     get_expression_values_from_probe_ids(probes_dict.keys()) #moving on
        print get_mni_coordinates_from_wells(well_ids)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create your own exception you create a class that inherits from Exception. I can't tell from your code where you expect to know there is some conditional failure, but this gives the general pattern

```
class GeneNameException(Exception):
    pass

try:
   ...
   if negative_condition:
       raise GeneNameException()
   ...
except GeneNameException as e:
   <clean_up>
```

Comment: Hi @achampion, the line is 'gene_name = row.strip()' from the .csv file, where there is a blank in that row that it is trying to get the gene_name for. I know about the general pattern, but I don't know how to write the 'negative_condition' part to catch the negative condition, which is a blank in the .csv file row.

Comment: row is a list of fields if there are no fields the `len(row) == 0`